# I need to know which app to download, how do i select the right one?

Tags: applications

I have an AT&T tablet I have inserted my sim card correctly. Now I need to know which app to get from the playstore that will give me a keypad so I can dial out and receive calls. Please help.
Thank you,
Marci

Comment: it depends. Does your Tablet supports voice call? You can mention tablet details so others can help. If you want to use VoIP(which uses Internet for placing/receiving calls) for audio calls, you can search for many popular apps on Play Store like WhatsApp, Line and so on...

Answer (score 0):

According to [theartiszan](https://support.t-mobile.com/message/354369#354369) on the T-Mobile support forum:

> The tablets are setup in a way in the US that you can not use them for phone calls.
>   So unless you root it and put in custom software you would not be able to use the standard phone features as such.

Depending on the model of your tablet, you may be able to modify your tablet with **root access** and activate these features, though keep in mind that **this process can be dangerous for the device and may also void your warranty**.

Alternatively, you can use a VoIP service such as [**Skype**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en-GB) or [**Hangouts**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk&hl=en-GB) to make Internet calls and send messages. Also, Google’s [**Hangouts Dialer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer&hl=en-GB) app lets you make and receive phone calls when you set up a [Google Voice™ number](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/165656?hl=en). Keep in mind that these services will use carrier data instead of carrier minutes.

*Note: While the quoted post is from the T-Mobile forums, it applies to all tablets in the U.S. including ones authorized by AT&T.*